# TensorFlow: Split a tensor into `batch_size` slices

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a rank-3 tensor named `tensor` of shape `[batch_size, axis_1, axis_2]` and want to split it into `batch_size` slices along the first axis like so:

```
batch_size = tf.shape(tensor)[0]

batch_items = tf.split(tensor, num_or_size_splits=batch_size, axis=0)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because the value of `batch_size` isn't yet known during construction of the graph.

How can I solve this?

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Expected int for argument 'num_split' not <tf.Tensor 'decoded_predictions/strided_slice_15:0' shape=() dtype=int32>.
```

Weirdly, trying to use `batch_size` in other TensorFlow functions seems to work:

```
tensor = tf.reshape(tensor, [batch_size, -1])
```

works fine despite the fact that the value of `batch_size` is unknown during graph construction.

Is the problem particularly with `tf.split()`?

Answer (score 1):

A work-around is to do:

```
batch_items = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda k: tensor[...,k],
                        elems=tf.range(batch_size),
                        dtype=tf.float32)
```

I'm still interested in better solutions though.